# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then'). Promise.resolve() won't work

Tags: javascript, mongoose, promise

For some reason my promise is not being resolved on time. I can't understand why, as my functions aren't asynchronous.

What I'm trying to achieve is to go through an entire array and resolve a promise only after all the elements have been validated (If necessary)

So whenever the resolving conditions are met, I call `promiseHelper = Promise.resolve(value)`. But for some reason I'm getting: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')` even though `promiseHelper.then` is written after the recursive function, which means the `helper` should be resolved before the `then` statement.

My question is: Why does the variable come to that part of the code without being a promise? And if possible, what's a better approach to achieve such functionality

Here's the code:

```
const cart = req.body.items; //Array of items
let promiseHelper;           
function recursiveCheck(cartIndex){
    let pieceOutOfStock = Piece.find({nombre: cart[cartIndex].name, cantidad: {$gte:cart[cartIndex].amount}});
    pieceOutOfStock.then(response =>{
        if (!response.length){  //If nothing on the query, resolve as false
                console.log("not enough:", element.amount, response.length);
                promiseHelper = Promise.resolve(false);
                return false;
                
        }
        else{
               if(cart.length > cartIndex+1){ //If something on the query and items left, validate next item
                    recursiveCheck(cartIndex+1);
               }  
               else{ //if last item, resolve as true
                    promiseHelper = Promise.resolve(true);
                    return true;
               }         
            }
    })
}

function getStock(){
   return new Promise (resolve =>{
          recursiveCheck(0);
          promiseHelper.then(response =>{
              if(!response){
                    resolve("reject")
              }
              else{
                    resolve("All good")
              }
          })
            
  })
}

    getStock().then(async response =>{
    //do some stuff

    }
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I found a work around for my code (still don't know the answer to the very first question tho)

`response(resolve)` allows me send my info to `query`. And finally the deepest else statement acknowledges the end of the loop, so I just started my final process in there.

Thanks all :)

```
    function recursiveCheck(cartIndex){
        return new Promise (resolve =>{
        let pieceOutOfStock = Piece.find({nombre: cart[cartIndex].name, cantidad: {$lte: cart[cartIndex].amount}});
        pieceOutOfStock.then(response =>{
            resolve(response);
        })
    }).then(query =>{
        if(!query.length){
            res.json({url: "http://localhost:3000/stockerror"});
            return query;
        }
        else{
            if(cart.length > cartIndex+1){
                return recursiveCheck(cartIndex+1);
            }
            else{
                stripeProcess();
            }
        }
    })
    }
    recursiveCheck(0);
```

Comment: Don't use the [promise constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/5459839).